# Absolute dir of an \input'ed file

Tags: input, external-files, currfile

I'm trying to make a header for all my slides that will include same image as logo. And I want that header to be correctly inputed from any tex file, i.e. use absolute path to included image.

Here is an MWE.

doc.tex:

```
\input{t/header.tex}
\begin{document}
\headerdir
\end{document}
```

t/header.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}[2012/05/06]

\def \headerdir {\currfileabsdir}

% use some file from headerdir, for instance in beamer:
% \institute{\includegraphics{\headerdir logo.pdf}}
```

But in `\headerdir` I get path of test.tex, not path of t/header.tex. Seems that is because \input doesn't do any smart thing and simply reprints the text in the main file. Any ideas how to get around that problem?

Comment: why do you want o use the absolute filepath? You do not use the absolute path to `article.cls` but you expect any document to find it. `\includegraphics` uses exactly the same filename library as `\input` and `\documentclass`

Comment: The idea is to have a dir with header and logo and include it in any tex file with one command and without any path variables (for ease of copying). For instance:
slides-1/slides-1.tex
slides-2/subdir/slides-2.tex
header/header.tex
header/logo.pdf ;
slides-1.tex and slides-2.tex need only one input command for inserting header if logo is included correctly in header.tex

Comment: That's exactly what David meant: if you move your file to your local texmf tree it will be always found in the same way article.cls is always found. (But you should give your header.tex and your logo  more unique names e.g. alvarbeamerheadertex.)

Comment: `\includegraphics{logo.pdf}` should be all you need just as `\documentclass{article}` is all you need.

Comment: Got it. Didn't know about local texmf tree. Thanks a lot!